# Can I add a garage outlet from existing interior circuit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, garage

I would like to add a receptacle to my garage.  Currently, all receptacles and lights in the garage are on a single 20A circuit that is solely dedicated to the garage.  For my new receptacle, I'd like to run it from a circuit that powers a couple of basement lights.  So at the end of the project, I will have a circuit that powers some basement lights and a receptacle in my garage.  Is this okay to do?  I've read about circuits needed to be dedicated to the garage, but I already have that.  Now I'm curious if I can add an additional receptacle from a different circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that.

If the **circuit** it's coming from isn't GFCI protected the **receptacle** will need to be, since it's in the garage.